# Vaadin field group is not working

Tags: java, vaadin7

I am trying to implement **vaadin fieldgroup** but it does not bind the values.

And it is giving me the following error :

`Communication problem
Invalid JSON response from server:`

Here is my code.

**Model Class:**

```
public class LoggedCustomer {

private String Id;
private String Name;
private String Cell;
private String email;
private String address;

public String getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    Id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}
public String getCell() {
    return Cell;
}
public void setCell(String cell) {
    Cell = cell;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

**Customer Layout Class:**

```
public class CustomerFormView extends FormLayout {

@PropertyId("id")
private TextField id = new TextField("Customer Id");

@PropertyId("name")
private TextField name = new TextField("Customer Name");

@PropertyId("cell")
private TextField cell = new TextField("Customer Cell Number");

@PropertyId("email")
private TextField email = new TextField("Customer Email");

@PropertyId("address")
private TextField address = new TextField("Customer Address");


public CustomerFormView() {

    setSpacing(true);
    addComponent(id);
    addComponent(name);
    addComponent(cell);
    addComponent(email);
    addComponent(address);
}
}
```

**Main UI Class:**

```
public class LoggedIn extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/loggedin", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = LoggedIn.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {    
    HorizontalLayout hori = new HorizontalLayout();
    setContent(hori);
    hori.setSpacing(true);
    hori.setMargin(true);

    Item customer = createCustomer();

    hori.addComponent(createView(customer));

    hori.addComponent(displayCustomer(customer));
}

private Layout createView(Item item) {
    VerticalLayout formLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    formLayout.setMargin(true);
    formLayout.setSizeFull();

    CustomerFormView productEditLayout = new CustomerFormView();
    formLayout.addComponent(productEditLayout);

    final FieldGroup binder = new FieldGroup(item);
    binder.bindMemberFields(productEditLayout);

    HorizontalLayout footer = new HorizontalLayout();
    footer.setSpacing(true);

    footer.addComponent(new Button("Save", new Button.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            try {
                binder.commit();
            } catch (InvalidValueException e) {

            } catch (CommitException e) {

            }
        }
    }));

    footer.addComponent(new Button("Cancel", new Button.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            binder.discard();
        }
    }));
    formLayout.addComponent(footer);

    return formLayout;
}

private Layout displayCustomer(Item item) {
    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();

    Label name = new Label();
    name.setPropertyDataSource(item.getItemProperty("name"));
    name.setCaption("Name");
    layout.addComponent(name);

    return layout;
}

private static Item createCustomer() {
    LoggedCustomer customer = new LoggedCustomer();
    customer.setName("");
    customer.setId("");
    customer.setCell("");
    customer.setEmail("");
    customer.setAddress("");
    return new BeanItem<LoggedCustomer>(customer);
}
}
```

this is the full code of my application in which I am working but the fieldgroup binder is not working and giving the error.

Kindly someone help me to identify where is the problem and what i am doing wrong in the code.

I shall be thankful.... :)

Comment: Please add exception or error which you receive

Comment: i did'nt get any exception this error comes in browser popup

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Communication problem
Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC to continue.Invalid JSON response from server: 

this is showing in pop up

Comment: Your code is working on my server.

Comment: is it working correctly??

Comment: UI is not very good but there is no error as you said. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/PVCxE.gif

Comment: ok thanks i will make server again :)